# Can't return value inside method java

Tags: java

maybe my problem is stupid, but i can't resolve it.

Here is my code:

```
public Velocity add(final Velocity velocity)
{
    Velocity vel;
    if(velocity.getClass().equals(CartesianCoordinate(x, y)))
    {
        double sumX = x + velocity.x;
        double sumY = y + velocity.y;
        Velocity v = new Velocity(CartesianCoordinate(x,y));
        v.x = sumX;
        v.y = sumY;
        vel = v;
    }

    if(velocity.getClass().equals(p))
    {
        do something...
    }
    return vel;
}
```

Can any one tell me why i cant return "vel", i dont want to create a class variable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can any one tell me why i cant return "vel"

Sure - you haven't given it a value if neither of your conditions is true. The variable isn't *definitely assigned*, so you can't read its value to return it. What do you *want* to return in that case? Is it even valid? Perhaps you should throw an exception in that case.

Personally I would actually return from each of the `if` blocks - I don't think the local variable is adding any benefit. At that point, it would be more obvious what was wrong:

```
public Velocity add(final Velocity velocity) {
    if (...) {
        ...
        return ...;
    }
    if (...) {
        ...
        return ...;
    }
    // What should we do if we get here?
}
```

Now that both of your conditions which *do* determine the return value just return it immediately, it's more obvious (IMO) that if you get to the bottom, that's because neither of the conditions has evaluated as `true`... so either you want to return some "empty" value, or a null reference, or throw an exception.

Of course, that's assuming that you don't want the second condition to effectively trump the first, which it does at the moment - if both conditions are true, the value set in the first block is presumably irrelevant, as it'll be overwritten by the second block.

It's also unclear what `CartesianCoordinate` does, but it's oddly named for a Java method - and if it returns a `Class<?>` that's definitely strange. What is `p` here? I don't know whether your real code is somewhat different to this, but even aside from the reason this won't compile, it smells fishy to me.

Comment: If i put "return v" inside IF statement i get error that my method has no return... That was the reason to create local variable...

Comment: @RuslanZarinaSeidovi: Well, not that it has *no* return - you'll get an error reporting that a return statement is *missing*, because you can get to the end of the method without returning anything. What do you want to happen if you get that far? You *either* have to return something, *or* throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Local variables have no default values and should be initialized.

If `val` was an instance field or a static field and it's not initialized, then it will return the default value when accessing it.

Comment: @RuslanZarinaSeidovi: It *compiles* - but that's not the same as it *working*. Don't just do this blindly - think about what it *means* to get to the end of the method without having hit either condition, and what you want to happen in that case.

Answer (score 0):

you can only return variables with a value. So there is a case possible where `val` does not have one.

The easies way to solve this is to initialize `val` directly on the declaration:

```
Velocity vel = null; //or
Velocity vel = new Velocity();
```

Or you need to add an `else` branch to your `if` statement where `vel` is initialized also.

```
if(velocity.getClass().equals(CartesianCoordinate(x, y)))
{
    double sumX = x + velocity.x;
    double sumY = y + velocity.y;
    Velocity v = new Velocity(CartesianCoordinate(x,y));
    v.x = sumX;
    v.y = sumY;
    vel = v;
}else{
    vel = null;//or
    vel = new Velocity();
}
```